# Stop flickering on hovering between divs of same class

Tags: jquery, class, flicker, jquery-hover, fadeto

I have 3 groups of divs which have a class dynamically assigned to them. When a user hovers over any of the divs, jQuery checks the class and fades the others with the same class. This works well but if I hover between the divs with the same classes the jquery seems to fire every time. Presumably because its re-checking the class and firing the effect.

My question is how can I stop the flicker when hovering between the same class divs?

The divs are all floated left with 1px margin. (I've tried removing the margin BTW).

My markup:

```
<div id="projects">

   <div class="p-1">IMAGE</div>
   <div class="p-1">IMAGE</div>
   <div class="p-1">IMAGE</div>

   <div class="p-2">IMAGE</div>
   <div class="p-2">IMAGE</div>
   <div class="p-2">IMAGE</div>

   <div class="p-3">IMAGE</div>
   <div class="p-3">IMAGE</div>
   <div class="p-3">IMAGE</div>

</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
    $('#projects div[class^=p-]').hover(function() {
        $('#projects div[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']').fadeTo(200, 0.2, function() {
        });
    }, function() {
        $('#projects div[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']').fadeTo(200, 1.0, function() {
        });
    });
```

And a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXHGe/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle. Adding the `stop()` function should be enough for what I understood from your comments:

```
$('#projects div[class^=p-]').hover(function() {
    $('#projects div[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']').stop().fadeTo(0, 0.2, function() { });
    }, function() {
        $('#projects div[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0, function() { });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hXHGe/9/

This functions stops any previous anymation. Since the hover in is prior to hover out it will stop the running animations and force it to remain faded to 0.2

Comment: Boom. Thats the one. I did already try this but I didn't work for me!? Perhaps my application didn't update. I just tried it again after your prompt and bingo, works. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you hover in between your individual `div` elements, the cursor is placed over a spot outside of your `div class` triggering the fade. As you continue to hover down the list of elements, the flickering effect becomes more obvious.

One way would be to restructure your markup so that the `.p-#` `div` is a parent div to those images so the hover effect is applied once to the child `div` elements, like so,

```
<div id="projects">

   <div class="p-1">
       <div>IMAGE</div>
       <div>IMAGE</div>
       <div>IMAGE</div>
   </div>

   <div class="p-2">
       <div>IMAGE</div>
       <div>IMAGE</div>
       <div>IMAGE</div>
   </div>

   <div class="p-3"> 
       <div>IMAGE</div>
       <div>IMAGE</div>
       <div>IMAGE</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

The individual children `div` elements could have unique identifiers if need be, but this will eliminate the `flicking` effect you are now seeing.

You can preview the code at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXSVe/)

The above fiddle was merely a demonstration, but with more information we could devise a better way to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I would change the markup but I really want to keep it as is for aesthetic reasons. I want the images to e able to spill on to separate rows. I've added a fiddle for clarification. ALso, I removed the margin etc so there shouldnt be a gap between each div (p-#)?

Comment: Why don't you add a new class as demonstrated by @Anthony to your current divs and then do the fadein to those new classes?

Comment: @JSantos Could you elaborate? FYI: each group of image/divs are created dynamically using a CMS

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nXSVe/1/ I've updated Anthony's fiddle with what I was meaning. I'm not sure where's your problem maybe that will fix it. Regards

Comment: @Victor With the issue appearing to be that your cursor could hover over the whitespace in between `div`'s triggering the flickering, you would need to encase the hover effect on a parent element to avoid the flickering (something as I had suggested). You would know what works with your markup, the idea was just to illustrate having the hover effect on a parent div.

Comment: @JSantos Ok, I see. That is way to do that and it work but I don't want the images to be grouped within a container like that. I'd like them to spill (like in my fiddle) over so that the image within the same group can be on 2 different rows. Does that make sense? Obrigado!

Comment: @anthony yes I understand. Thanks. I'm going to try a few things an post back any results.

Comment: @Victor yes it does make sense. Without using the div I can only guess that you need to do some javascript analysis